# How to remove multiple courses in bulk in Moodle

Tags: moodle, bulk

Is there a way to remove multiple courses at once?
It seems I can only do this one by one.

Perhaps there is a better way, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: You should accept the answer if you like it, by clicking on the green tick. This notes your problem solved in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 17):

Without writing any code, the easiest way to delete multiple courses is to:

1. Create a category (e.g. called 'delete me')
2. Select multiple courses and move them all into this category
3. Delete the category and select 'delete all' (rather than 'move to another category')

Comment: Thanks, that's a really smart way to do it!